# Using dlls of sdk inside my app without copy and register

Tags: c#, dll, sdk, biometrics

I want to include all the needed dll´s inside my C# project, So you do not need to copy them to system32 and register them.

I tried with costura.fody and other ways, but I cant get it work...

I created a "libs" folder inside my project and I copy all the dll´s. Then I add one of this dll (the other are dependencies, as I know) as a reference.

But I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in myapp.exe

Additional information: Could not retrieve COM class generator for component {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} Due to the following error: 80040154 Unregistered class (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

When I copy all the dlls to my system32 folder and register one of them with:

```
regsvr32 %windir%\system32\zkemkeeper.dll
```

all works well...

**EDIT:**

As I said the sdk of zkteco (a biometric scanner) has multiple dll. But I only can add one as reference. the others throws me the next error:

`A reference to XXX.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accesible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component`.

So I don't know what is the problem here...

The dll's:

[image]

My reference:

[image]

Properties of each of this libs:

[image]

My folder with all dll's:

[image]

Properties of each of this libs:

[image]

Comment: I dont know that, mate. Could you tell me if this is what I need...?

Comment: What is prívate COM deployment?

Comment: Also, why are you using _"Embedded Resource"_ for the **Build Action**?  That only works if you have the appropriate "un-embedding" code which you don't appear to mention anywhere

Comment: By ignorance. I do not know how I should proceed to do what I described in my question

Comment: OK, when you set the **Build Action** to _"Embedded Resource"_, how are you un-embedding them?  Do you extract the files out at runtime or anything?  If you don't do that then it won't work?  Wishing you well

Comment: I figured that was done automatically .. obviously I'm wrong. I am finding it very difficult to understand these concepts. I probably mixing things up. Could you tell me the correct address? Sorry to be so heavy

Comment: Maybe I need to use other value for build action? I So sorry about my unstable question. I dont know how to explain me better..

Comment: That's ok :)  It is hard to answer this because I don't have zkteco on my computer.  Could you try keeping **zkemkeep** as _isolated_ but mark the other files as **Build Action** = "None";  **Copy to output directory** = "Always"?  Let me know how it goes

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that But also doesnt work.. If you have some free time and want to help me... In this url you can download the standalone sdk with examples and de dlls.. tomorrow I will open a bounty for this question (50 reputation..) . Otherwise thank you very much for your patience :) you are very polite

Comment: https://www.zkteco.com/support/SDK/39_55.html

Comment: Oki.  I'll try to take a look at the link.  If not me, I'm sure someone else with more skill will be able to help you out, especially if you use a _bounty_. :)

Comment: I've deleted some of my comments (particularly the one about editing questions), because in this case I agree, editing your question _is_ the right thing to do.  :)  Good evening

Comment: Thank you very much micky. I will open a bounty although any person resolve my doubt before opening it, sure. We must reward those who help.  :) Again, thank you and good evening

Comment: Bounty is started :)

Comment: You could regsvr your components from your private folder, technically you don't have to put them in system32, but if anyone else uses them, they will use the last ones that were regsvr (so yours if you registered the last). What's better is "registration-free COM": http://blog.functionalfun.net/2012/09/a-quick-guide-to-registration-free-com.html

Comment: So you recommends me this system called "registration free com"?  Could you put this as an answer?

Comment: @SimonMourier Any answer...?

Comment: @MartaGom - I didn't see your comment (it was not specifically directed to me). I don't think it's really enough for an answer. Did you manage to use reg-free COM?

Answer (score 1):

---

After seeing the update to the question and chatting more with OP regarding his specific case, I've come to realise that **my answer** may **not** be very **useful** as it currently stands.  I'll leave it here for now in case I think of anything more. :)

---

> Using dlls of sdk inside my app without copy and register

Yes you can use *Isolated COM*.  Essentially it means Your app can be deployed along with the COM dlls but your manifest file makes it so you don't need to have the COM dlls registered.

Simply click the **Isolated** property on the COM reference and this updates/creates the manifest.

### See also

- [COM Interop, isolation and excluding duplicate references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968689/com-interop-isolation-and-excluding-duplicate-references)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please take a look to my updated question

Comment: Maybe my little command of English has caused you to have that impression on me. I consider that my update still refers to the same question, as I still do not know how to integrate the dll with my project...

Comment: The bounty is soon to expire. I give you the points, because you have been very kind. What a pity that nobody could help me ... winning those points is not easy

Comment: Wow!  Thank you very much!  I'm sorry that no one else was able to help.  All the best